# Gulp task compiling babel

Tags: gulp

In full disclosure I'm fairly new in the Mean Stack Mundo,

My gulp task look like this:

```
gulp.task('compile:babel', () => {
return gulp.src(['**/*.es6.js', '!node_modules/**'])
           .pipe(babel({optional: ['es7.decorators']}))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
})
```

When I run gulp via command line I get this error:

```
C:\projects\BellaMusic\source>gulp
C:\projects\\BellaMusic\source\gulpfile.js:30
gulp.task('compile:babel', () => {
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\Gizzmo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gizzmo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Gizzmo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
```

I have no idea what is causing this or where to begin any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `es6` syntax in your gulpfile (namely `() =>{}` function. Does your `node` support it? For the sake of debugging, try to stick with std `function(){}`.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, that was the problem, I've inherited an environment that was running node version 0.12.7. Updated the node version and voila!

Comment: cool :) BTW, you can upgrade to newer node easily (check out nvm project), or you can use babel to transpile (also) your gulpfile, so you can use new cool syntax.